# Java: How to extract members of annotation

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

How to extract members of Java annotation. E.g. we have following one:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface XYZ {
    int min() default 0;
    String name() default "";
    String [] colors();
}
```

I have a class, methods of which are annotated with XYZ. How do I extract annotation info for each of class methods? Like what I get in brackets when print annotation to the console:

```
@com.stackoverflow.XYZ(min=0, name=Jack, colors=[red, white, blue])
```

It's important to mention, that I don't know about XYZ prior to runtime. In other words, I'd like to analyze arbitrary class using Reflection in runtime and extract detailed annotation info in runtim, also.

Comment: Have you tried something? Read the javadoc?

Comment: Sure I did! Just was looking for an easier way to extract information I need. Now it seems only possible to analyze Annotation itself using Reflection again and invoke its specific methods on annotation object.

Doesn't seem javish at all - more like old ugly C++ like constructions.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a contrived example which prints "red" (you would need to add appropriate exception handling etc.):

```
public class Annotate {

    @XYZ(colors="red") public void m() {}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Annotate a  = new Annotate();
        Method m = a.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("m");
        XYZ ann = (XYZ) m.getAnnotation(XYZ.class);
        if (ann != null) {
            System.out.println(ann.colors()[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `ann` would be null if the method weren't annotated with `@XYZ`.

Comment: In my situation you don't know aprioiry, that method is annotated or if it is, with which annotations! Task is to analyze arbitrary class with arbitrary annotations.

Comment: @DenisKulagin then you can call `m.getDeclaredAnnotations()` to get all the annotations applied to the method. Then loop over the result (which may be empty) and do what you need to do...

Answer (score 0):

You could try this I am using XmlElemet annotation on getName() method of Employee class:

```
 public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException,
        SecurityException {
    Method method = Employee.class.getMethod("getName");
    XmlElement anno =method.getAnnotation(javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement.class);
    System.out.println(anno.name());
    System.out.println(anno.defaultValue());
}
```

}